# Appending all for loop dicts into single list

Tags: python, json, django, list, api

I just learnt django and I am getting data from api and looping through the `json` and appending the data into the list. but When I use `.map()` function in `react` then the data is appending in list (from for loop) like

```
[
    {
        "results": {
            "id": 544,
            "name": "User_1",
        }
    },
    {
        "results": {
            "id": 218,
            "name": "User_2",
        }
    },
    {
        "results": {
            "id": 8948,
            "name": "User_3",
        }
    },
    {
        "results": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "User_4",
        }
    },
]
```

It is not appending like (Like I want)

```
[
    results : [
        {
           "id": 544,
           "name": "User_1"
        },
        {
           "id": 218,
           "name": "User_2"
        },
        {
           "id": 8948,
           "name": "User_3"
        },
        {
           "id": 9,
           "name": "User_4"
        }
    ],
     "length_of_results": 25,
]
```

views.py

```
def extract_view(request):
    results_list = []

    // api url for explanation only
    get_response = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers"

    if get_response.status_code == 200:
        for result in get_response.json():
            results_list.append({"results": result})

    results_list.append({"length_of_results": len(results_list)})

    return Response({"data": results_list})
```

I know, In for loop it is appending every result within it with every iteration but I also want to assign all the responses within **results** list. Because I will add a append another field after for loop.

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by `map` function iterating over list:

```py
dict(results=list(map(lambda x: x["results"], response)))
```

**Full working example:**

```py
response = [
    {
        "results": {
            "id": 544,
            "name": "User_1",
        }
    },
    {
        "results": {
            "id": 218,
            "name": "User_2",
        }
    },
    {
        "results": {
            "id": 8948,
            "name": "User_3",
        }
    },
    {
        "results": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "User_4",
        }
    },
]

results = dict(results=list(map(lambda x: x["results"], response)))
results["length_of_results"] = len(results["results"])

>> {'results': [{'id': 544, 'name': 'User_1'},
>>   {'id': 218, 'name': 'User_2'},
>>   {'id': 8948, 'name': 'User_3'},
>>   {'id': 9, 'name': 'User_4'}],
>>  'length_of_results': 4}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working But How do I add another field of  `length_of_results` after for loop ? It is not adding init.

Comment: You did not provide it in your expected output format. How do you want it? Please update your expected output JSON to get clear idea.

Comment: Just a moment.....

Comment: What is the logic for `"length_of_results": 25` in your expected output?

Comment: As I defined in `question` I am appending the length of list  after for loop `results_list.append({"length_of_results": len(results_list)})`

Comment: Your expected result does not look like valid object or JSON. Arrays don't have keys. It should be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

By doing

```
results_list.append({"results": result})
```

you are creating a new dictionary with the value being result which I believe is a dictionary itself. So you should be able to just do this:

```
if get_response.status_code == 200:
    for result in get_response.json():
        results_list.append(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer But I will add another field after `for loop` and I don't want to mix it (new appended field) with `for looped` results.